# Selecting input that is not a parent or child to dropdown in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to get value of input champion that's above the dropdown with val function. Here is also whole fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/84cxtru7/

```
 function val(elm) {
            var championsWithExtraSpells = ["Aatrox", "Elise", "Fizz", "Heimerdinger", "Jayce", "Lee Sin", "Nidalee", "Rek'Sai","Twisted Fate"];

            var championName = $(elm).prev("input").find(".ChampionInput").val();
            console.log(championName);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

        championNumber = 1;
        $('a#AddChampion').on('click',function(){

            $('div#ChampionInput').append(
            '<div class="Champion" data-id="'+championNumber+'">\
                 <a href="#" class="Remove">Remove</a>\
                 <br>\
                 <input type="text" class="ChampionInput" list="champions" name="champion[]" placeholder="Champion '+championNumber+'">\
                 <datalist id="champions"></datalist>\
                 <a href="#" class="AddSpell">Add Spell</a>\
                 <br>\
             <div>');

        $('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.AddSpell',function(){
            $(
            '<div class="Spell" data-id="'+$(this).children( "div.Change").length+'">\
                <select name="change['+$(this).parent('div').data('id')+'][]" onchange="val(this)">\
                   <option value="Passive">Passive</option>\
                   <option value="Q" selected>Q</option>\
                   <option value="W">W</option>\
                   <option value="E">E</option>\
                   <option value="R">R</option>\
                </select>\
                <input type="text" name="championSpell['+$(this).parent('div').data('id')+'][]">\
                <br>\
                <div class="Change">\
                <textarea type="text" size="20" name="SpellDescription['+$(this).parent('div').data('id')+'][]" placeholder="Enter Description" />\
                    <select name="SpellChange['+$(this).parent('.Champion').data('id')+'][0][]">\
                       <option value="buff">Buff</option>\
                       <option value="nerf">Nerf</option>\
                       <option value="new">New</option>\
                       <option value="change">Change</option>\
                       <option value="bugfix">Bugfix</option>\
                    </select>\
                    <a href="#" class="AddChange">Add Change </a>\
                    <a href="#" class="RemoveSpell">Remove Spell</a>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
            ').appendTo('.Champion[data-id='+$(this).parent('div').data('id')+']');

        });
    });
```

Comment: Where you call your `val()` function?

Comment: <select name="change['+$(this).parent('div').data('id')+'][]" onchange="val(this)">\

Comment: Sorry! but honestly, your code is a mess. You must clean that up for someone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$(elm).closest(".Champion").find(".ChampionInput").val();
```

`elm`(the `select`) is inside `div.Spell` which is inside `div.Champion` where `input.ChampionInput` is placed.

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84cxtru7/1/)**</kbd>

<sup>Note that I have changed the location of your code in the fiddle from "*OnLoad*" to "*Wrap in head*". That is because on load event those functions `var()` and `change()` are declared the in load event scope, so the select's `onchange` event can't reach them.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you couldn't just use the class as the selector `var championName = $(".ChampionInput").val();` or add an id to the input element and select that way?

Aside from using .find() with a context I tend to use the jQuery traversal methods sparingly. Many are dependent on maintaining the same markup structure, which—in a large code base with multiple developers—can be difficult to control.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, you should really clean up your code. Having that said, if you can add a class to your select, such as:

```
<select name="change['+$(this).parent('div').data('id')+'][]" class="change-me">\
```

Then you can, get the value of `input.ChampionInput` like below. Note that I've changed your function from `val()` to `getVal()`.

```
function getVal() {
    var championName = $(this).closest(".Champion").find(".ChampionInput").val();
    console.log(championName);
}
```

And then, within `.ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#second_form").on("change", "select.change-me", getVal);
});
```

Take look at this [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/84cxtru7/2/).